# How to extract that pair from pairwise.t.test with a specific value?

Tags: r

I think I have a somewhat simple question.

```
q1 <- with(airquality, pairwise.t.test(Ozone, Month))
```

and I want to find the minimum of this, I know that I can use

```
min(q1$p.value, na.rm = TRUE)
```

and say that it is `0.001`.
My question is how can I find the pair that gave me this specific value from my `q1`? Sorry if it is kind of vague. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you provide an example we can use, so here's the example from the `pairwise.t.test` documentation.

I perform the t-test then print the p-value matrix. I find the indices of the element that is equal to the minimum p-value and use these indices to pull out the row and column names.

```r
# Air quality example
attach(airquality)
Month <- factor(Month, labels = month.abb[5:9])
res <- pairwise.t.test(Ozone, Month)

# Print resulting p-value matrix
print(res$p.value)
#>              May        Jun         Jul         Aug
#> Jun 1.0000000000         NA          NA          NA
#> Jul 0.0002638036 0.05112741          NA          NA
#> Aug 0.0001949061 0.04987333 1.000000000          NA
#> Sep 1.0000000000 1.00000000 0.004878798 0.003878108

# Find indices of minimum value
ind <- which(res$p.value == min(res$p.value, na.rm = TRUE), arr.ind = TRUE)

# Pull row and column names
rownames(res$p.value)[ind[1]]
#> [1] "Aug"
colnames(res$p.value)[ind[2]]
#> [1] "May"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Your data is basically a good example of the data frame i'm working with. My ind is int[0, 1:2] which results in both my rownames and colnames to give NA.?

Comment: Can you add the data (using the output from `dput`) to your question so that I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: wait nvm, i guess saving my minimum p.value doesnt let me compare with the res$p.value. But when i typed it all in using min(res$p.value, na.rm = TRUE) it worked. it's all solved thank you for your help!